# Playlist not refreshed after adding a track via API

Tags: deezer, slack-api

I'm trying to integrate Deezer with Slack. A user would be able to type `!play Blackmill - Let It Be` in Slack and via a webhook to Deezer API a track would be added to our room's playlist.

To add a track I post to `http://api.deezer.com/playlist/123456789/tracks?songs=22945401`, it returns `true`, and the track is actually added. But in the browser where the playlist is currently playing I don't get the new track until a page refresh, so the playlist just stops after the last track that was already there.

I know there's collaborative playlists which somehow work in a similar fashion, so I'm hoping it's possible to implement what I described.

Is there a way I can tell Deezer to refresh the playlist? Or maybe there's a better approach altogether?

Comment: When you use DZ.api to add the track to the playlist (I presume you do that?), you just add it to the playlist but not in the queue, it is normal. 

You have to implement the callback success function of DZ.api and add it to the current queue with DZ.player.addToQueue method (cf http://developers.deezer.com/sdk/javascript/loadtracks), and all will work normally.

Comment: On a side note, will this project be available for use ! I'd love to test this feature :)

Comment: @Fred_Dzr it's a webhook from Slack, there's no browser and JavaScript involved. Actually, now I'm just experimenting with it in the API explorer

Comment: @XGouchet Maybe, if I find out how to overcome this issue. But I won't mind if you steal my idea to do it yourself :)